# Catalan assimilation of 's' /s/ → [ʃ] after palatal consonants 'ny' /ɲ/ and 'll' /ʎ/

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, romance-languages, palatalization, catalan

## Question

I've noticed a phenomenon in (Central) Catalan speech that I had seen no mention of when studying the language. In words with a final *-nys* or *-lls*, the *s* is assimilated and becomes palatal `[ʃ]` (or possibly `[tʃ]`).

e.g.

- *any*  `/aɲ/` > *anys*  `/aɲʃ/`
- *aquell* `/əˈkɛʎ/` > *aquells* `/əˈkɛʎʃ/`

My questions are:

1. how widespread is this phenomenon in Catalan?
2. in dialects with this feature, does it apply in all `/ɲ/`, `/ʎ/` + `/s/` environments or is it limited to certain words (e.g. only those with word final *-nys/-lls*)?
3. at what point did this phenomenon begin to emerge?

Comment: .(i am a fan of this question). A pattern that comes out is V+ny+s or V+ll+s where V is a vowel (also assuming that V+j is effectively V (as j is a glide)). Are there contradictions to this? If not I think we can build up on this if you have examples that tell us that C+ny/ll+s is not palatalizing.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no examples of C + *ny/ll* + *s* in any Catalan word. All words which have a consonant before *ny/ll* are prefixes to *ll* initial words (*en*, *des*, *tras*... etc, plus a few surnames and toponyms with initial *San/Mon*) or have V + *tll* + V where the *t* is assimilated, exhibiting (dialect depending) as `[ɫɫ]`, `[ɫ]`, `[ʎʎ]` or `[ʎ]` e.g. [*almetlla*](http://dcvb.iec.cat/results.asp?word=ametlla).

Comment: The following map shows the different realisations of `/ʎs/`: http://aldc.espais.iec.cat/files/2013/07/23-Palatalització-o-no-de-la-s-en-el-segment-final-lls.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [L’Atles Lingüístic del Domini Català](http://aldc.espais.iec.cat/files/2013/07/23-Palatalitzaci%C3%B3-o-no-de-la-s-en-el-segment-final-lls.pdf)

[image]

### Native speakers

Here are some self-aware discussions by native speakers noting the phenomenon:

- https://www.racocatala.cat/forums/fil/176056/grups-lls-i-nys
- [https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciació-del-grup-nys-y-lls.2541968/](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciaci%C3%B3-del-grup-nys-y-lls.2541968/)

### Grup d/Estudi de la Variació Dialectal (GEVaD)

> En posició final de mot, la consonant nasal palatal palatalitza la fricativa alveolar següent (`-[ɲʃ]` a *a**nys***, *empe**nys***, *me**nys**tenir*). El mateix s’esdevé, en major o menor grau segons els dialectes, en el cas de la consonant lateral palatal (`-[ʎʃ]` o `-[ʎs̠]` a *a**lls***, *bu**lls***, *cabe**lls***).

- [*La fonologia del català*](http://www.ub.edu/GEVAD/wp-content/files_mf/1335261573340295_Fonologia1.pdf), Maria-Rosa Lloret, Universitat de Barcelona

### Diccionari de Dubtes del Català Oral (DDCOR)

Recordings of words containing *nys* and *llys* in various Catalan dialects:

- [*punys*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=cHVueXM%3D), [*menyspreable*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=bWVueXNwcmVhYmxl),<sup>*</sup> [*cavalls*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=Y2F2YWxscw%3D%3D), [*cervells*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=Y2VydmVsbHM%3D), [*conills*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=Y29uaWxscw%3D%3D), [*reculls*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=cmVjdWxscw%3D%3D), [*segells*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=c2VnZWxscw%3D%3D), [*senzills*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=c2VuemlsbHM%3D), [*setrills*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=c2V0cmlsbHM%3D), [*esculls*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=ZXNjdWxscw%3D%3D), [*Collserola*](http://www.llengua.info/ddcor/fitxa_mot.php?mot=Q29sbHNlcm9sYQ%3D%3D)<sup>**</sup>

<sup>* seems to contradict Maria-Rosa Lloret's description of this only occurring word finally</sup>
<sup>** note, to my ear palatalisation of the *s* does not seem to occur with this toponym in any dialect illustrated</sup>

### DCVB

The DCVB entries on [*any*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=any) and [*menys*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=menys) note this in some dialects:

> F<sub><sup>ON</sup></sub>.: `áɲ` (pir-or., or., occ., val., bal., alg.).
>
> **Pronúncia del pl. *anys*:**
>
> - `áɲs` (Perpinyà, Noedes, Fontpedrosa, Prats de M., Sallagosa, Angustrina, Porté, Puigcerdà, Martinet, Ribes, Ripoll, Olot, Capmany, Cadaqués, Bagà, Berga, Manresa, Granollers, Sort, Oliana, Tremp, Balaguer, Artesa, Tamarit de L., Fraga, Ciutadella, Eiv.);
> - `áɲʃ` (Pobla de L., Torre de C., Tremp, Ponts, Arbúcies, Caldes de Ma., Vilafranca del P., Sta. Col. de Q., Eiv.);
> - `áɲʧ` (Pobla de L., Torre de C., Boí, Vilaller, Tremp, Balaguer, Ll., Arbeca, Tarr., Val., Llíria, Gandia, Porreres);
> - `áјɲs` (Puigcerdà, Gòsol, La Seu d'U.);
> - `áјɲʃ` (Mercadal, St. Climent de Men.);
> - `áјns` (Manacor, Santanyí, Porreres).

> F<sub><sup>ON</sup></sub>.:
>
> - `méɲs` (or., bal.);
> - `meɲʧ` (occ., val.).
>
> La conservació de la forma *menys* en el llenguatge quotidià es limita gairebé a les comarques valencianes; en les altres regions ha estat substituït per la forma castellana *menos*, inacceptable en bon català.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think palatalization of final s in such environments is the most common outcome, and I wouldn't trust native speakers not versed on linguistics since the difference is not phonemic, let alone represented in spelling.
   I also have the feeling that palatalization in *nys* is clearer than in *lls*. My *s* in *anys* is a downright /ʃ/, but in *valls* it's so soft that I'm not even sure if it's palatalized at all. See [Lluís' tweet](https://twitter.com/FocFollet/status/981206484506828800) (and he's quite a knowledgeable guy IMHO) where he transcribes *anys* (before vowel) as /aɲʒ/, while Tonifranro's version (Valencian *apitxat*) uses /aɲtʃ/.
2. I don't think "final" is a necessary condition, it just happens that the vast majority of instances are plurals from a word ending in *-ny* or *-ll*. The only counterexamples I can think of are *menystenir* and *menysprear*.
3. I have no idea, but my feeling is that since the very first moment these sounds come into contact it's totally natural to assimilate them. Note that the opposite direction also takes place: in words with *nx* or *lx*. See DCVB's entries for e.g. *llanxa* and *Elx*.